# Rails 4 - ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper select method is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using New Relic I've noticed that some selects, with many options (~2000) rendered very slowly, around 60ms. When creating the select tag with simple methods which loops all options it took 7-10ms.

Is there a reason this method is so slow when there are many options? are there any alternatives?

Comment: I don't think there will be any real alternatives as you're still going to loop through.  You could pluck the necessary columns which might help.  I'd also argue if you have anywhere even remotely close to 2000 options for a select you have gone wrong in your design.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should not have ~2000 options within a select. If you want to keep the select tag, you could paginate what options appeared within the select tag (put a `LIMIT` on your query) and cache the results in the view, then send for the next set of results only if they scroll to that point.